# How to automatically add numeric special methods to a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to somehow intercept *numeric* magic or dunder methods for a class in Python? The `__getattr__` works for all "normal" methods, but it will not intercept methods like `__add__`, `__mul__` and so on. I thought there might be some metaclass for this? The built-in [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) package seems to be somewhat close to what I am looking for.

For example. I want to create a class `Number` that will intercept all methods calls to `__add__`, `__mul__`, `__truediv__` and so on. This does not seem to work:

```
class Number(int):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a number"

a = Number()
b = Number()

c = a + b # this will not preserve the subclass (Number)
```

What I would want:

```
class Number(NumberMetaClass):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a number"

    def intercept_special_numeric(self, special_method, *args):
        print("intercept")
        return special_method(*args)

a = Number()
b = Number()

c = a + b # subclass is preserved and this will print "intercept"
```

Or maybe just:

```
class Number(NumberMetaClass):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a number"

    def __getattr_special__(self, dunder_attr):
        print("intercept")
        return getattr(Number, dunder_attr)
```

Comment: You could maybe inherit from `int` or `float`.

Comment: Hmm, but I want to preserve the subclass when using methods like ```__add__```. I think that inheriting from ```int``` will only silence the error?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you show an example?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I made an edit to my post. I hope my intention is a bit more clear.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just overriding the dunder methods you're interested in?

Comment: It's the same reason for using the ```dataclass``` package. I want to override every numeric dunder method and I think it would be a lot of boilerplate code for doing this on every one.

Comment: Although, It might suffice with doing some kind of automatic override outside the class scope by using "monkeypatching". I just thought there would be some kind of rudimentary way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, You want to inherit from a type and also want to intercept it's methods. Am I right?

You could do the same thing with metaprogramming and metaclasses. But I think using 'class decorator' is much more simpler. Here is my approach:

```
from functools import wraps


def intercept_numeric_methods(cls):
    def method_decorator(fn):

        @wraps(fn)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            print('Intercepted')
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    numeric_methods = {'__add__', '__mul__'}

    for method_name, method in int.__dict__.items():
        if method_name in numeric_methods:
            setattr(cls, method_name, method_decorator(method))

    return cls


@intercept_numeric_methods
class Myclass(int):
    pass


obj1 = Myclass(10)
obj2 = Myclass(20)

print(obj1 + obj2)
```

I've just added `__add__` and `__mul__`. Add the name of the methods you want into `numeric_methods` set.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the best approach so far.

Comment: I just tested it, I actually do not want to ```MyClass``` to be a int but instead a custom class. If i replace ```Myclass(int)``` with ```Myclass(object)``` It seems to throw an error when doing ```obj1 + obj2```.

Comment: @Kevin But Kevin `object` class itself doesn't have numeric magic methods. You said you want to intercept them, so if the class itself doesn't have that methods, what do you want to intercept ?

Comment: I see, I ```Myclass``` to behave like an object with numeric magic methods defined. I know that the ```object``` class itself does not have these methods predefined, which is why I was looking for a metaclass to replace ```object``` with.

Comment: Effectively, I want ```Myclass``` to behave like an object with all numeric magic methods overridden, but I want to do this in a convenient manner - without manually writing down every numeric magic method.

Comment: Your solution does exactly this, but when adding ```obj1``` with ```obj2``` it seems to simply cast it to an ```int``` - which is not my intention.

Comment: @Kevin Another problem comes up, how do you want to define your let's say `__add__` method? There isn't a generic "adding" method to use for all types. Do you intend to use `operator` module for example?

Comment: I don't need it to work for all types, just the ```Myclass``` type essentially. Make the assumption that operating types are of the same type ```Myclass```

Comment: @Kevin you mean your `Myclass` class has already numeric magic methods and you want to intercept those ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232311/discussion-between-soroush-bakhtiary-and-kevin).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, if that is achieving, what you want to achieve, but the following code outputs the result below.

```
class Number(int):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a number"
    def __add__(self, other):
        print("intercepted")
        
a = Number(3)
b = Number()

c = a + b  # this will not preserve the subclass (Number)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
intercepted
None
```

So when the addition is executed, you enter the `__add__` method, where the "intercepted" is printed, but it will return None, which is assigned to c, so it's not intercepting the addition. If you don't want to assign a value to c, you could raise an error in `__add__`. If you want to assign the sum to c, you just adapt the `__add__` like follows.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    print("intercepted")
    return super().__add__(other)
```

Note, in the initial version None is assigned to c, because in Python every method implicitly returns None, there is no such thing as a void method without return. When not specifying a return statement, None is returned by the method.

Comment: Thanks, although this is not what I was hoping to achieve. I do not want to manually add the methods ```__add__```, ```__radd__```, ```__iadd__``` and so on.

Comment: Now I understand it. I guess you have to in order to achieve that. Maybe you could define something like an abstract parent class that defines these methods once, and then you can just inherit from that. That's the only thing I can come up with at the moment.